# Does dockerized github actions support network options for docker run parameters

Tags: docker, github-actions, building-github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

I am using self hosted github runners for vpn access to some software and I am trying to use a dockerized github action on the self hosted runners but I am having issues because I need to specify the --network host flag when github action runs docker run. Is there a way to have the github action use the network of the host?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not possible. It's not available on steps either. Options are available on  [jobs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idcontaineroptions) though. The only other way is for you to create a composite action and run `docker run ...` directly in it. Here is one that I wrote for my own workflow. It's slightly more complicated but it allows you to automatically pass environment variable from the runner to the docker container based on the variable name prefix:

```yaml
name: Docker start container
description: Start a detached container

inputs:
  image:
    description: The image to use
    required: true
  name:
    description: The container name
    required: true
  options:
    description: Additional options to pass to docker run
    required: false
    default: ''
  command:
    description: The command to run
    required: false
    default: ''
  env_pattern:
    description: The environment variable pattern to pass to the container
    required: false
    default: ''

outputs:
  cid:
    description: Container ID
    value: ${{ steps.info.outputs.cid }}

runs:
  using: composite
  steps:
    - name: Run
      shell: bash
      run: >
        variables='';
        for i in $(env | grep '${{ inputs.env_pattern }}' | awk -F '=' '{print $1}'); do
          variables="--env ${i} ${variables}";
        done;
        docker run -d
        --name ${{ inputs.name }}
        --network host
        --cidfile ${{ inputs.name }}.cid
        ${variables}
        ${{ inputs.options }}
        ${{ inputs.image }}
        ${{ inputs.command }}
    - name: Info
      id: info
      shell: bash
      run: echo "::set-output name=cid::$(cat ${{ inputs.name }}.cid)"
```

and to use it:

```yaml
      - name: Start app container
        uses: ./.github/actions/docker-start-container
        with:
          image: myapp/myapp:latest
          name: myapp
          env_pattern: 'MYAPP_'
          options: --entrypoint entrypoint.sh
          command: >
            --check
            -v
```